# How can one count the number of characters used in a command just executed in Bash?

Tags: bash, debugging, bash-trap

Let's say I want to have a line print in such a way that it fills the space remaining in a terminal after an executed command. It could look something like this:

```
user1@host1:~>ls----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have some functions that allow a line to be printed across a terminal. These ultimately use information about the terminal dimensions in order to do this. The functions are as follows:

```
returnTerminalDimension(){
    dimension="${1}"
    if [ "${dimension}" = "size" ]; then
        stty size
    else
        if [ "${dimension}" = "height" ]; then
            stty size | cut -d" " -f1
        else
            if [ "${dimension}" = "width" ]; then
                stty size | cut -d" " -f2
            fi
        fi
    fi
}

printCharacter(){
    character="${1}"
    numberOfTimesToPrintCharacter="${2}"
    for ((  currentPrintNumber = 0;  currentPrintNumber<=${numberOfTimesToPrintCharacter};  currentPrintNumber++  ))
    do
        echo -n "${character}"
    done
}

printLine(){
    numberOfLines=1
    terminalWidth="$(returnTerminalDimension "width")"
    numberOfCharactersToPrint=$(echo "${numberOfLines}*(${terminalWidth})-1" | bc)
    printCharacter "_" "${numberOfCharactersToPrint}"
}
```

There is a way to have a command executed right before a specified command is executed. This command (here, `date` is used as an example) can be specified as follows:

```
trap 'date' DEBUG
```

So, this would run right before the execution a specified command at each use of the carriage return.

How could I count the number of characters used in a command that has just been executed in order to combine all of these tricks to allow a line to fill the remaining after the command?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for something similar to `man bash PROMPT_COMMAND` If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt. However, in your case, if I understand it correctly, you just want to trigger the running before a specific command? (perhaps your PROMPT_COMMAND could test for the caller and respond appropriately, or store the length of each command in a temp variable or file?) You are talking about a single execution on the command line correct? Or are you talking about a series of returns within a script?

Comment: The trap doesn't run before the carriage return because the command line isn't evaluated until the carriage return is read (and echoed). Also, `DEBUG` traps execute after every command. Try `trap date DEBUG; for i in {1..10}; do : ; done`

Comment: By the way: `repeat() { printf %*s ${2:-$(tput cols)} "" | tr ' ' "${1:--}"; }`